# how to run Kafka command in gitlab CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, gitlab

I am new to GitLab and Kafka and do not have more ideas on how to run the Kafka command using shell script through the GitLab CI/CD pipeline.

Following configuration I am using to achieve this but getting exceptions, is there anything I am missing or configured incorrectly? Please suggest

In .gitlab-ci.yml

```
run_kafka:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
  script : 
       - . demo.sh
```

In demo.sh

```
   kafka-consumer-groups --command-config ./config.properties --bootstrap-server "pkc-6ojv2.us-west4.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092" --group my-created-consumer-group --topic SampleTopic --reset-offsets --to-current
```

In config.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=pkc-confluent.cloud:9092
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="" password="";
```

exception getting when pipeline is running

```
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeGroups(api=FIND_COORDINATOR)
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeGroups(api=FIND_COORDINATOR)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.$anonfun$resetOffsets$1(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foldLeft(IterableOnce.scala:675)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foldLeft$(IterableOnce.scala:669)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foldLeft(Iterable.scala:933)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.resetOffsets(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:432)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.run(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:76)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:59)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeGroups(api=FIND_COORDINATOR)
```

Comment: Command looks fine. It's simply timing out. Are you sure outgoing network connections are allowed from gitlab?

Comment: I am not sure, how will I check this and allow this outgoing network connection ?

Comment: Read the documentation? Ask Gitlab support?